# The opposite of xenophobia

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes

*No. I'm not talking about xenophilia.*

In both these senses, xenophobia and xenophilia relate to foreigners or strangers.

I am looking for a fear of the same people who live in the same country as you, not foreigners but localers, so to speak.

Essentially I am looking for the opposite of ***xeno***. Ive gone thru the [Wiktionary entry for xeno](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xeno-), but I couldnt find any antonyms.

Is there already a term for fear of localers?  If not what appropriate greek/latin prefix would work with the phobe/phile suffixes?

Comment: The opposite of being afraid of foreigners is not being afraid of foreigners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certain political party used the neologism ***oecophobia*** in this sense, "fear of one's home", from Greek *oikos* "house, home". *Xenophobia* means "fear of the strange", from Greek *xenos* "strange, foreign, guest" (usually with a positive connotation).

Comment: I've seen it more often spelled as _okiophobia_, especially now that [Oikos-brand yogurt](http://www.oikosyogurt.com/) is popular.

Comment: @Malvolio - You're saying you see this *often*? [grin]  (I'm chuckling over the likely misprision for an irrational fear of Greek yogurt!)

Comment: @Malvolio: ...but that is not actually the proper way to incorporate Greek words into Latin and then into English, as is conventional.

Comment: @Cerberus -- I don't know if there is a "proper" way.  Certainly the habit of transliterating the kappa into "c" instead of "k" has led to the widespread mispronouncing of "Celt" and "cyanide".

Comment: @Rob_Ster -- often enough.  _Oikophobia_ (like _hoplophobia_) does seem like a useful neologism to describe a common but neurotic political tic.  "No advanced industrial nation except the US has the death penalty."  "South Korea?  Japan?  Singapore?"  "Uh...."

Comment: @Malvolio - I rather like it. I'm just thinking about how some of my lesser pupils would deal with it - you know, the youngsters with a four-word vocabulary (i.e., "God," "like," "man," and "dude"...)

Comment: @Malvolio: How do you mean 'mispronouncing'? C before e should normally be pronounced /s/ in English, so I don't see any problems there?

Comment: @Cerberus -- it _should_ (etymologically) be pronounced /k/ and is only pronounced /s/ because of the accident of transliteration a thousand years ago.

Comment: @Malvolio: Okay, but that applies to so many—if not most—of our borrowed words! And also of our inherited, Old-English words! Pronunciation changes. It happens to be traditional in English (and all other European languages I know) to translitterate Greek words through Latin, so that's basically the reason. Deviations from this rule are few and recent. Of course anyone should make his own decisions about whatever spelling he prefers.